# Leaked Object Is CFArray, But Line Detected That Causes The Leak Does Not Contain CFArray Object

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have 2 100% occurring leaks at launch of the app. The leaked objects as stated by the instrument are CFArray Objects.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When I click on one leak object and check it's retain cycle. Here's what I see:

[image]

I then click on the line shown on the left hand side that causes the leak to check the code, then this came up:

[image]

My problem is, this line `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue` that the instrument states doesn't even return any `CFArray` objects. So I don't understand where did this `CFArray` came from.

Comment: There is a mismatch here. I don't understand what the 2 bytes from the line `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue` are supposed to be. The *CFArray* leak to two lines below, on the line `NSArray *wifiInfoList ...`. This is about arrays (internally its a CFArray instead of a NSArray). The stacktrace confirms this as it contains `__CNCopySupportedInterfaces`.

Comment: The static analyser is usually quite good at finding these things.

Comment: @Codo Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Codo. Looks like I focused too much on the line `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue` and didn't realize that what really cause the leak is the unreleased CFArray (supportedInterfaces) under else statement. Just did a `CFRelease(supportedInterfaces)` then everything is fine now.